# Missing whitespace before "group by" but is still valid psql query

Tags: whitespace, psql

Can someone explaine why this psql query is valid:

```
select count(*) from employee where accountid=9group by companyid;
```

Comment: There are a few situations where the parser isn't very strict about whitespace. You've found one of them. It might be worth mentioning to pgsql-bugs, but it could just be a corner case where it's hard to make the parser strict

Answer (score 0):

[SQL-92 BNF Grammar here](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html) explicitly states that **`delimiters (bracket, whitespace, * etc) are valid to break up the tokens`**, which makes the white space optional in various cases where other delimiters already break up the tokens.

**`Whitespace is optional in pretty much any language where it is not absolutely necessary to preserve boundaries between keywords and/or identifiers`**. You could write code in C# that looked similar to your SQL, and as long as the compiler can still parse the identifiers and keywords, it doesn't care.